# What is the Android equivalent of iOS's didReceiveRemoteNotification?

Tags: android, ios

The full method signature is...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

What I want to be able to do is have the device respond when a push notification arrives. For example, the app might automatically navigate to a particular screen to show some data that's identified in the notification.

Comment: I would be a lot more helpful if you described what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Equivalent Method is **public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
            scheduleJob();
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow();
        }

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
```

For reference see [1](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L45-L82) [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Answer (score 0):

[PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)) is what you're looking for.

This is how you'd use it :-

```
    Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```